# Using current_user outside any action of custom controller in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, cancan

I have to build site that only registered users can access. As a inexperienced RoR developer I tried to set up authentication system described in [Railscasts episode #250](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) and planed to use [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) as authorization system. While using Cancan *check_authorization* I had a problem with *current_user* variable, that is defined in private helper method in **application_controller.rb**:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

And it looks like it is invisible to cancan *check_authorization* method in every other controller since it is placed outside any actions (thank you debugger gem).
Now any user (does not matter if he is logged in) can access login and registration pages (OK), but everyone cannot access any other action in controllers I have defined *check_authorization* (and this method must present in all of them)(not OK)
Question is: what would be the best way to fix this problem using rails conventions?
Alternative would be to use cancan *authorize!* method for every action, but it looks incorrect. Also, when I worked with devise gem, there was no problems like this, but for me it looks like using this authentication system is overly heavy for light projects like mine.

Comment: sorry but what is your problem? if you have current_user method in your application_controller.rb then you should be able to use it inside all of your controllers as they inherit from ApplicationController

Comment: @Mandeep, I thought so too, but by using debugger gem found that current_user exist only after 'def index' and before it's 'end' (or any other action insted of index). You can not use methods inherit from ApplicationController just next line after 'class UsersController < ApplicationController'

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question *i think you want to authorise certain actions in your controller with the current_user method you have defined in application controller*(correct me if i'm wrong). what you can do is use a [`before filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)  and define a private method in your controller to *check if current user exists and if it doesn't then simply redirect to root page*

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, except: [:index, :show] #list your actions in except array where you don't want to check for current user

  private

  def authenticate
    redirect_to your_path, notice: "You must login first" if !current_user  # if current user doesn't exist it will redirect to your path with notice
  end
end
```

Comment: Well... Yeah, that is the problem and an acceptable solution, but question was about cancan methods finding the current_user. At least I am sure that current_user does not exist before I call 'check_authorization' or any other (cancan) method. Probably because of unexpected definition (My guess). Also 'before_action :authenticate' will not find 'def require_login' - probably mistake.

Comment: @VladRoker my bad i just copy pasted code. The private method should be named authenticate. Updating it and you said in your question `for me it looks like using this authentication system is overly heavy for light projects like mine` so thought you wanted to do it yourself

Comment: I was talking about devise and similar authentication systems (mostly hard to configure. A lot of options etc.), that could be replaced by simple have only email and password authentification. CanCan is [claimed to be as simple as possible by it's author - Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan), and I thought using it would be right choice (it has some benefits). Yet, thank you for answer. I will mark it as accepted until there will be solution with using cancan gem.

Comment: @VladRoker if you want a simple authentication then why use cancan or devise. Make your own authentication system and in the process you'll get to learn things too. There is a railcast of authentication from scratch. In fact in rails 4 it is even more simple by using has_secure_password

Answer (score 0):

Use a `before_filter` in your controllers like this:

```
before_filter :current_user
```

This will run the method before every action in the controller. You can include `:only` or `:except` to include or exclude certain methods if you need.

Comment: Profit from cancan is that all users abilities are stored in same place (app/models/ability.rb). I could define authorization in _before_filter_, but for every controller and with no cancan methods like _can_ & _cannot_.